# how to scan all clients if they contain files with a specific line of text

Tags: command-line, server, grep, client

So I am going to ask for something major here and that is if I can scan from one device all other connected devices to see if they have a specific line of text in any of their files.

It is a bit like using the `grep -rl "text to find" "file location"` command but that does it on one machine you are currently on. now what I am asking is having the machine I am on scan all other devices in the same folder for files containing the text that has to be found and if it does printing the machine name with the files containing the files like it does on one machine

```
/etc/asterisk/sip.conf
/etc/network/interfaces
/etc/firewall
```

This is how it does on one machine but now I hope it is possible to do it like this

```
machine name    /etc/firewall
machine name    /etc/network/interfaces
```

Or if it can even be done a bit nicer

```
machine name

    /etc/firewall
    /etc/network/interfaces
```

I might be asking the impossible but I have seen ubuntu do the impossible before

update1: since I got a solution from Rinzwind I was able to get on certain machines but others had port 22 closed so still having that problem
update2: problem with the port has been solved by adding `-p 220` between `user@host` and `"grep` in Rinzwind's solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
ssh user@host -p port "grep -rl 'help' /home/" >> /tmp/search.txt
```

will return any file inside /home that contains "help" on remote server {host} on {port} using {user} and add it to "/tmp/search.txt". This assumes {host} will accept {user} as a valid user and might prompt for passwords.

For this to work over multiple machines you could read a config file with users and hosts and iterate over them. It would probably be easier to do this in "python" or "perl" as you can easily manipulate and format the results on each pass and then write to stdout the results.

Comment: well all machines have a root account with the same name so that won't be a problem but i tried our code but my machine comes with the following root@pe-fw:~# ssh {root}@{host} "grep -rl '82.204.38' /etc/" >> /tmp/search.txt
ssh: Could not resolve hostname {host}: Name or service not known'
did i miss something or am i a complete idiot mind you still learning the ropes and all

Comment: Change {host} for the actual hostname it is registered on your machine (or use an IP address ;) ) Drop the {} since those where to identify a variable in my code ;)

Comment: okay so if i were to do the following
ssh root@192.168.1.1-254 "grep -rl '82.204.38' /etc/" >> /tmp/search.txt
that should ask all those machines in the range right?

Comment: If you want to query a large number of hosts you may find `parallel-ssh` (from package `pssh`) useful

Comment: @steeldriver okay so if i were to use pssh instead of ssh the resault would be the same correct?

Comment: @delfiler AFAIK the main difference is that it will accept a list of hosts (or a filename containing a list of hosts)

Comment: @steeldriver it is what i am asking for right i mean i do want to check a large range of machines that are connected to one another

Comment: @delfiler no you will need to supply 1 ssh for 1 IP in the method you posted 1 hour ago ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind ah okay, well not to sound degrading or anything negative, cause the command you gave is really useful, but I was looking for something that could do multiple machines at a time or maybe even a whole range of ip's. But that might be a bit too demanding is my guess, for the machine and ubuntu itself but I guess people are going to prove me wrong

Comment: "but I was looking for something that could do multiple machines" you understand the concept of a reading a file with ipadresses and a for-next loop?  What you want is a coding question that I myself would solve using python.

Comment: @Rinzwind yeah i do and that is fair to say but i am walking into one tiny problem (nitced it myself also a little too late) that is that at most machines port 22 is closed and instead port 220 is being used for ssh, my co-worker told me (yes started recently and didn't know that)

Comment: user@host:port ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind it didn't work but i found a work around that is as following
`ssh user@host -p`

Comment: hmm :D probably they way it needs to be yes (I am used to :port from something else ;-) )